# Incorrect sql syntax while querying sql server

Tags: sql-server, syntax-error

hoping someone can help me clean up a query I'm having a problem with. I'm attempting to split my results in half after I've returned the latest revision from each group of revisions.

I can split the results in half with this:

```
    SELECT *
      FROM 
      (
        SELECT *, ntile(2) over(order by ID) as tile_nr
        FROM dbTable
      ) x
    WHERE x.tile_nr = 1
```

I can get the latest revision from groups of revisions with this:

```
    SELECT b1.*
        FROM dbTable b1
        INNER JOIN 
          (
              SELECT ID, max(revision) as revision
              FROM dbTable
              GROUP BY ID 
           )   as b2
           ON b1.ID = b2.ID and
           (
               b1.revision = b2.revision or b2.revision is null
           )
```

But when I try to merge these queries into one like this:

```
    SELECT *
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT *, ntile(2) over(order by ID) as tile_nr
        FROM
        (
            SELECT b1.*
            FROM dbTable b1
            INNER JOIN 
              (
                  SELECT ID, max(revision) as revision
                  FROM dbTable
                  GROUP BY ID 
              )  as b2
             ON b1.ID = b2.ID and
              (
                   b1.revision = b2.revision or b2.revision is null
              )
        )
    ) x
    WHERE x.tile_nr = 1
```

I get an "Incorrect snytax near ')'" error. It appears to not like the last parenthesis.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of those cases where indentation is helpful in debugging:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
(
    SELECT *, ntile(2) over(order by ID) as tile_nr
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT bt.*
        FROM dbTable b1
        INNER JOIN 
        (
            SELECT ID, max(revision) as revision
            FROM dbTable
            GROUP BY ID as b2
            ON b1.ID = b2.revision or b2.revision is null
        )
    )
) x
WHERE x.tle_nr = 1
```

Specifically, your innermost SELECT includes an ON clause that doesn't make sense within that scope. You need to generate the subquery result set, alias a name to it, then use that aliased name in your join condtions:

```
    SELECT bt.*
    FROM dbTable b1
    INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT ID, max(revision) as revision
        FROM dbTable
        GROUP BY ID
    ) as b2
    ON b1.ID = b2.revision or b2.revision is null
```

Followup edit:

It looks like aliasing the subquery that your NTILE() SELECT solves the issue:

```
SELECT *, ntile(2) over(order by ID) as tile_nr
    FROM 
    (subquery) as subQ
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @lyrisey. Wow I realized I made several mistakes in the syntax while posting. I had to retype it as I'm working on another machine due to security restrictions. I've edited my original post with the corrections.

Comment: Updated. It's generally good practice to alias subqueries so you're always working with known names.